# Displaying nested data from network return using Parse Javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, json, parse-platform

I am obtaining the following response from my Parse Server using the Parse Javascript SDK:

[image: Network Return]

Using the code below, I am successfully outputting the inventoryQTY into the stock variable, but cannot work out how to output GTIN_13 which is nested in Product_Temp?

```
for (i in results) {                                    
    var stock = results[i].get("inventoryQty")
    var Barcode = results[i].get("GTIN_13");
    console.log("Stock is " + stock);
    console.log("Barcode is " + Barcode);
}
```

I have also tried:

```
    var Barcode = results[i].get("Product_Temp.GTIN_13");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code to get the value of GTIN_13:

```
for (var i=0; i < results.length; i++) {                                    
    var product = results[i].get('Product_Temp');

    for (var productIndex = 0; productIndex < product.length; productIndex++) {
       var barcode = product[productIndex].get('GTIN_13');
       // your code to process the barcode ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've figured it out by using your example code, but done it as follows (pasted full function for reference): (In next comment due to length restrictions)

Comment: function getPosts() {
                var query = new Parse.Query("Inventory");
                query.include("Product_Temp");
                query.find({
                    success: function (results) {
                        for (i in results) {
                            var Product = results[i].get("Product_Temp");
                            var Barcode = Product.get("GTIN_13");
                            console.log("Barcode is " + Barcode);
                      };
                 };
           });
};

Comment: @MrT, if you think that your answer is more correct, you should publish it as an answer and accept it (https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).